# Stored Procedure not returning values

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a stored procedure to update a field with an instructor who makes less than a certain value. The procedure creates and runs, but when it runs it only returns the rows. No data shows up once I call the procedure. It only has one field to update so I don't need to implement cursors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists update_salary$$
create procedure update_salary()
begin
declare Instructor_ID int;
declare Salary int;
select Instructor_ID, Salary from Instructor where Instructor_ID = 13;
if Salary < 53000 then
update Instructor set Salary = 61000 where Instructor_ID = People.Person_ID;
end if;
end $$
```

Comment: 1. Use should use `SELECT ... INTO` to fetch columns into variables 2. you update instruction has syntax error, because there is no People table

Comment: I've tried select Instructor_ID, Salary into ... I've tried non declared variables but it gives errors and I'm not sure if that's how it's done.

Comment: it is how it is done `declare myvar int; select \`column\` into myvar from table;`

Comment: So instead of 2 declare statements I have 4?

Comment: no, just two: `declare var1 int; declare var2 int; select \`col1\`, \`col2\` into var1, var2 from table;`

Comment: Oh ok got it, but now I'm getting result consists of more than 1 row

Comment: then you have two rows for instructor_id=13, check whether it is PK or unique index on this column, also add `limit 1` to be sure :)

Comment: `select \`Instructor_ID\`, \`Salary\` into Instructor_ID, Salary from \`Instructor\` where \`Instructor_ID\` = 13 limit 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure where People.Person_ID comes from, but if your goal is to update a specific record in the Instructor table only if the Salary is under 53 000, you should use a simple UPDATE query, like so :

```
UPDATE Instructor SET Salary = 61000 WHERE Instructor_ID = 13 AND Salary < 53000
```

To see the results of the update afterwards, you need to run a SELECT statement, like so :

```
SELECT Instructor_ID, Salary FROM Instructor WHERE Instructor_ID = 13
```

Comment: Instructor_ID is FK to Person_ID. I was just testing out different ways to do so. Also the update statement has the same issue I'm having.

Comment: What is the issue, or more clearly, what is the expected output of the procedure ?

Comment: The expected output is taking the instructor with salary less than X and change it to Y and return show the instructor table with the new Y.